# How to send a query or stored procedure execution request to a specific location/region of cosmosdb?

Tags: python, rest, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to multi-thread some tasks using cosmosdb to optimize ETL time, and I can't find how, using the python API (but I could do something in REST if required) if I have a stored procedure to call twice for two partitions keys, I could send it to two different regions (namely 'West Europe' and 'Central France)

I defined those as PreferredLocations in the connection policy but don't know how to include to a query, the instruction to route it to a specific location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you could specify that on would be the options objects of the requests. However there is nothing related to the regions.

What you can do is initialize multiple clients that have a different order in the preferred locations and then spread the load that way in different regions.

However, unless your apps are deployed on those different regions and latency is less, there is no point in doing so since Cosmos DB will be able to cope with all the requests in a single region as long as you have the RUs needed.

Comment: "as you have the RUs needed." Is the key there. 

My stored procedures operates bulk updates, I/O is the key to performance there. Since the RUs are specified for each region, I can max both regions out.

Comment: @VincentChalmel Yeah that's fair then. Each region has it's own RUs so if you need to make the most of the juice you're paying you should just have multiple clients for each region.